# Specifying download timestamp limit of html5 audio element

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I am making an app for a book, and part of it involves audio. The book is broken up into chapters and each chapter has about 10 sections. The sound engineer who made the audiobook broke the files up into chapters, but the book itself is broken up into readable sections. Therefore I need to way to play only a specific part of the chapter.

I know you can use URLs to specify timestamps using `...mp3#t=00:03:26`. But I'm not exactly sure of the behaviour the download will play after.

The *starting* of the file works fine, but I'm worried about what happens when it gets to the end of a section. I suppose I could put an event listener on the audio element to check to see if the time has reached the next section's timestamp. The issue I'm facing is that involves trying to conserve bandwidth because that's our main cost.

If the browser decides to download the rest of the audio file, then let's say you're at section 3 and your browser downloads section 4,5, and 6. Then when you go to section 4 it re-downloads a part of what it already downloaded.

There are a number of 'other' solutions but what I mainly want to is understand how the browser determines the timestamp at which it 'stops' downloading. I assume that when it is playing live, it only downloads x amount of seconds in advance. If this is a low number, it's not a big deal. But if the browser skips ahead it could incur a lot of costs, in which case I would need to 'cap' it somehow.

The audio engineer doesn't want to break the files up into sections because then there are quality losses for re-compression.

Comment: The solution here is to have the audio engineer crop the sections from the source material. Also, browsers cache downloaded media. Scrolling back to section 4 doesn't re-download section 4.

Comment: I will most likely do it myself in the end using the ffmpeg copy codec command which can losslessly splice mp3s. Still would be good to have this question answered for future people. Sound engineer does not want to play ball.